# How to use layer normalization in tensorflow 1.12?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am stuck with tensorflow 1.12, and I need to use layer normalization. I can't find some examples of this, and as I am new to tensorflow I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

`tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm` is the function that I want to include in my `tf.keras.Sequential()` like this -

```
        self.module = K.Sequential([
            tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(trainable=True),
            K.layers.Activation(self.activation),
            K.layers.Dense(units=self.output_size, activation=None, kernel_initializer=self.initializer)
        ])
```

I also tried using

```
self.ln = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(trainable=True)
### and in call()
self.ln(self.module)
```

In all the cases, it throws the error at the line defining `tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(trainable=True)`-

```
TypeError: layer_norm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

I understand that the inputs need to be given as the argument to layernorm, but if I want it to trainable, it can only be defined in `__init__()`. Where am I going wrong?

I use mainly PyTorch, so it is quite obvious that I am not able to grasp the ideology of `tf`. Any suggestions will be very helpful!

Comment: You can't use sequential like that afaik. It's used for linking up keras layers so they can automatically work out their input. You're getting an error because you have just put in part of a tensorflow function/layer that requires you to explicitly specify an input tensor. Can't really mix and match like that.
There is a keras batch norm layer that might be of interest to you?

Comment: I want to use layer norm instead. I ended up calling layer_norm finally in `call()` and it seems to be working. Do you see any pitfall with that?

Answer (score 0):

`Sequential` needs to be initialized by a list of `Layer` instances, such as `tf.keras.layers.Activation`, `tf.keras.layers.Dense`. `tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm` is functional instead of `Layer` instance.

There is a third party implementation of layer normalization in keras style - [keras-layer-normalization](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-layer-normalization). But I haven't tested in tensorflow.

Comment: TypeError: layer_norm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

As per the error, you have not passed 'input' argument to layer_norm().